# Can Indy requests being fingerprinted?

Tags: delphi, indy

I'm using Delphi 10 developing a project that automatically requests HTTPS to verify a third party service. Two days ago, IdHTTP started to return "403 Forbidden Error".
So I installed Fiddler and added the fiddler's ssl certificate into Windows to decrypt SSL traffic. In IdHTTP I did:

```
HTTP.ProxyParams.ProxyServer := '127.0.0.1';
HTTP.ProxyParams.ProxyPort := 8888;
```

And like magic, the https service correctly answered 200 OK.
So I removed the certificate and got 403 again, now observating the OnStatusInfo of IdSSLOpenSSL, which is:

```
SSL status: "before/connect initialization"
SSL status: "before/connect initialization"
SSL status: "SSLv2/v3 write client hello A"
SSL status: "SSLv3 read server hello A"
SSL status: "SSLv3 read server certificate A"
SSL status: "SSLv3 read server key exchange A"
SSL status: "SSLv3 read server done A"
SSL status: "SSLv3 write client key exchange A"
SSL status: "SSLv3 write change cipher spec A"
SSL status: "SSLv3 write finished A"
SSL status: "SSLv3 flush data"
SSL status: "SSLv3 read server session ticket A"
SSL status: "SSLv3 read finished A"
SSL status: "SSL negotiation finished successfully"
SSL status: "SSL negotiation finished successfully"
Cipher: name = ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256; description = ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
; bits = 128; version = TLSv1/SSLv3;
```

Doesn't look to have any TLS errors here. My code is this simple:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  http: TIdHTTP;
  ssl: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  HTMLSource: String;
begin
  http:= TIdHTTP.Create(Nil);
  ssl:= TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(Nil);
  try
    ssl.SSLOptions.Method:= sslvTLSv1_2;
    ssl.SSLOptions.SSLVersions:= [sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];
    ssl.OnStatusInfo:= OnSSLStatusInfo;
    http.IOHandler:= SSL;
    //http.AllowCookies:= true;
    //HTTP.ProxyParams.ProxyServer := '127.0.0.1';
    //HTTP.ProxyParams.ProxyPort := 8888;
    //http.Request.Accept:= 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8';
    //http.Request.UserAgent:= 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36';
    //http.Request.Connection:= 'keep-alive';
    http.HandleRedirects:= true;
    http.ReadTimeout:= 15000;
    HTMLSource:= http.Get('https://redacted.com/');
    if (http.ResponseCode = 200) then
      Memo1.Text:= HTMLSource;
  finally
      ssl.Free;
      http.Free;
  end;
```

All commented lines were tried as solutions, none of them worked. And with Fiddler certificate installed and proxy setted, I don't need cookies, user-agent, or anything else to work. Maybe the service somehow fingerprinted Indy automatic requests, and Fiddler's proxy spoof this? Still don't know how to fix the issue without using Fiddler proxy/certificate.

The logs for IdConnectionIntercept are:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: redacted.com
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: identity
User-Agent: Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)
---
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Server: cloudflare
Date: Thu, 11 Jun 2020 00:24:04 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 151
Connection: keep-alive
CF-RAY: 5a172fe59902d07a-CWB
cf-request-id: 03425c437f0000d07a0696c200000001

<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>cloudflare</center>
</body>
</html>
```

The logs running with IdHTTP setted to Fiddler's proxy (and Fiddler certificate to decrypt SSL traffic are):

```
CONNECT redacted.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Pragma: no-cache
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Host: redacted.com
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)
---
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established
FiddlerGateway: Direct
StartTime: 21:29:27.471
Connection: close
---
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: redacted.com
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: identity
User-Agent: Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)
---
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Thu, 11 Jun 2020 00:29:19 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d2453057d13003b17569dc77d925d4bd61591835359; expires=Sat, 11-Jul-20 00:29:19 GMT; path=/; domain=.redacted.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
X-Sorting-Hat-PodId: 80
Location: https://www.redacted.com/
X-Request-Id: df4074f2-a140-4488-9831-848a432641b8
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none
CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
cf-request-id: 0342610fb40000d082169fc200000001
Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 5a173792bedcd082-CWB
alt-svc: h3-27=":443"; ma=86400

<html><body>You are being <a href="https://www.redacted.com/">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

Some headers of the 301 answer were removed for privacy.

Somehow the certificate installed by Fiddler to decrypt SSL traffic is making the request work. I just don't have any theory about why, and how to fix this issue inside the code.

Comment: Rather than using Fiddler, another way you can capture `TIdHTTP`'s HTTP traffic over SSL/TLS is to assign one of Indy's `TIdLog...` components to the `TIdHTTP.Intercept` property. That will then log all outgoing data before it is encrypted, and all incoming data after it is decrypted. That will give you a better chance of seeing exactly what `TIdHTTP` is sending to the server without Fiddler tweaking it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: edited the answer to include logs captured by IdConnectionIntercept. I'm using this one because TIdLogEvent didn't showed anything on Sent/Received events. This one seen to show some logs, but nothing that sugests an answer.

Comment: "*I'm using this one because TIdLogEvent didn't showed anything on Sent/Received events*" - yes, it does (`TIdLogBase` is derived from `TIdConnectionIntercept`). You probably just didn't set it up correctly.

Comment: Fiddler uses a certificate only when communicating with the client (`TIdHTTP`), but not when communicating with the target server when an HTTP `CONNECT` command is being used, as it is just acting as a straight pass-through, so the client still negotiates the SSL/TLS handshake with the server so the server can validate the client's identity if needed.  So something else is going on.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, when I remove the fiddler certificate (but keep proxy setting on IdHTTP) it stops working and gives 403 again. Maybe it's a server-side problem, that makes any sense? Still don't know what theoretically could be. Not an expert in TLS.